# Function to extract a string between the 2nd and 3rd comma

Tags: ms-access

I am looking for a function that will extract all the information between the 2nd and 3rd comma.

[DropOffAddress] = "Hotel, 1234 Johnson St, Minneapolis, MN 55449"

I am looking to extract just "Minneapolis" from the string above.

If it is less complicated, just extracting "Minneapolis, MN 55449" is workable.

I am using a query to display the information and I know the info I will always be between the second and third comma in the field [DropOffAddress]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can in VBA code use this:

```
dim strResult   as string
strResult = split(strSourceString,",")(2)
```

So split is zero based, and hence "2" will get us the 3rd token out of the string delimited by ",".

You can't however use VBA split() function in sql query, but you can use it in code as per above.

If you need this in a query?

Then in a standard code module, then place this function.

```
Public Function MySplit2(v As Variant, ix As Integer) As String

  MySplit = ""
  
  If IsNull(v) Then Exit Function
  
  If v = "" Then Exit Function
  
  Dim vBuf As Variant
  
  vBuf = Split(v, "|")
  
  If ix > UBound(vBuf) Then Exit Function
  
  MySplit = vBuf(ix)
  

End Function
```

Now, in a sql query, say one column was UserName (first name,LastName)

```
SELECT id, MySplit([UserName],0) as FirstName,
MySplit([UserName],1) as LastName, City, State from tblCustomers
```

Comment: I should have noted that I tried using the Split function as an example of what I was trying to do but you are correct, it does not work within a query.

Thanks Albert

Comment: Ok, then we can still make this work. I mean leaving out that huge, large, massive, and important detail changes this question by a lot. But, sure, we can make it work in a query - see my edit